# Retrieve Data from Dynamics CRM via Web Form

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

Ok, I'm striking out with this.  I'm wondering if there is a plugin or something available where I can place a form on a website which queries our CRM online and returns data.  For example, I'd like for ANY website user to enter a zip code into a form and a radius (10 miles, 100 miles, etc.) and have it return to them the name and contact info of Account records who are within the radius of that zip code.

Anyone doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, lots of people do this.  Here is a link to get started:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334357.aspx

Comment: Thanks Zach.  Any ideas about an already existing solution (so I don't have to write one)? :-)

Comment: From my experience wrappers around the XRM code are highly proprietary, so if you want to build your own functionality you are probably doing so from scratch.  However, there may be companies out there that offer pre-built widgets that you can stick on your web application to interface with common CRM entities.  If no widget exists yet that meets your needs I am sure there are companies out there that would be happy to build you one custom.